# Can entire functions have simple poles?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am a physicist, and I found the claim that "entire functions do not have poles at finite $z$." Can somebody who is more versed than me in complex analysis tell me whether it is true or not?

Comment: It's true by definition of "entire", namely "holomorphic at all points in $\mathbb C$.  So there are no singularities at all, poles or essential, at finite points.

Comment: That's the definition of entire: no poles except perhaps at infinity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function

Comment: Thanks. Do we know anything about the inverse of an entire function $f(z)$, that is, $1/f(z)$ ?

Comment: You wrote "inverse" but you then say 1/f(z) which is the [b]reciprocal[/b]of f, not its inverse function.

Comment: OK, language issue here. I meant the reciprocal.

Comment: @user247327 1/f(x) is the multiplicative inverse. "Inverse", when dealing with functions, is generally understood to mean the compositional inverse, so using it to mean the multiplicative inverse is misleading, but not entirely incorrect.

Comment: @user247327 This is precisely why I added the $1/f(z)$. No need to be pedantic.

Comment: @Jens if $f(z)$ has zeros, then $1/f(z)$ has poles, so is not entire. An entire function must have range all of $\mathbb{C}$ except perhaps minus a single point, so most holomorphic functions do have zeros, and then $1/f(z)$ is not entire. But not all functions, eg $\exp(z).$

Comment: @ziggurism Thanks! The fact that entire functions may not assume all values is the Little Picard Theorem, right?

Comment: @Jens Yes, I believe that is the name of that theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Entire functions do not have poles at finite z"

The definition of an entire function implies that.

So the answer: It's true